# Instalador reconhecido como vírus

Tags: python-3.x, .exe

Olá, criei um programa em python 3.6 e criei o executável dele para Windows com Cx Freeze, depois criei um instalador para ele utilizando o Inno Setup 5.6.
Quando compartilhei com meus amigos para eles testarem, o windows impedia de abrir o instalador, dizendo q n era um programa reconhecido e poderia causar danos ao computador.
Como posso fazer meu programa se tornar reconhecido para o windows?

Comment: Provavelmente é porque o Windows não consegue garantir que a fonte do programa é segura através do certificado digital. Não entendo muito do processo, mas [nesse site](http://www.techracket.com/windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-path-or-file/) tem um tutorial de como exportar e instalar a chave do seu computador em outros, tornando-o uma fonte confiável.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O seu vírus não foi reconhecido como vírus. Ele foi marcado como um **programa de uma fonte não reconhecida pela Microsoft**, o que é muito diferente.

Todo "menino do computador" sabe que `parente leigo com acesso de administrador + Windows = ninho de malwares a procriar e evoluir`. Tem sido assim desde o Windows 95, talvez até mais cedo. Em uma tentativa de limpar a reputação do Windows de sistema vulnerável e colocar a culpa no usuário, a Microsoft de vez em quando lança alguma iniciativa como o [User Account Control](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control), que é o que você viu.

Funciona assim: toda vez que o usuário tentar instalar ou executar algo que pode danificar o computador, ele dá um aviso: *"olha, se você rodar essa coisa você pode me f... lascar, e a culpa vai ser só sua, viu?"*. Obviamente, o usuário dá a esse pequeno aviso o mesmo tratamento que costuma dar aos acordos de licença.

Então, você tem duas formas de lidar com isso:

- **Desativar o UAC:** deixo a seu critério pesquisar como fazer isso. Infelizmente, é uma alteração que tem que ser feita máquina a máquina, localmente, e afeta não apenas a sua aplicação. Custoso e discutivelmente antiético.
- **Comprar uma licença do [Authenticode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20686377/2263584)** e assinar digitalmente o seu aplicativo. Fica a seu critério também estudar o que é uma assinatura digital, e como ela garante a autenticidade do que é assinado dessa forma. Isso não garante que alguém não usará a assinatura em um vírus, mas é caro, burocrático e eles vão saber onde você mora.

Comment: Agora está pior ainda, porque além desse aviso, o windows 10 também exibe uma janela bonitinha ao melhor estilo "google" avisando que a aplicação não está na loja dela, portanto, não é possivel garantir segurança na instalação(quando é um aplicativo win32). Mesmo ignorando, essa janela aparece em seguida. Proteção adicional, pena que quase ninguem se importa com ela, mas depois que detona o sistema, a culpa é do "Rwindows" e não do *BIOS*.